# Связать таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть несколько таблиц с одинаковыми полями, которые связаны с 2-мя основными таблицами. Такой подход мне не нравится.

Например: Таблица с отелями имеет связанную таблицу с картинками по ключу hotel_id > id
и таблица Рестораны имеет связанную таблицу с картинками по ключу restaurant_id > id

Потом есть еще несколько таблиц 
Тип заведения Отель, Гостиница, Мотель итд.
И так же с ресторанами Ресторан, Кафе, Столовая

Как можно сделать уникальные 2 таблица
Images & Types?

Comment: А кто делал анализ предметной области? вот того и спрашивайте, как он был выполнен, и какие именно результаты привели к существующей структуре. А затем вносите изменения в анализ - корректировки структуры вылезут сами.

Answer (score 1):

тут простого ответа не будет. :)

код, работающий с такими данными может весьма неожиданно их выбирать и апдейтить.

так что нормализация таблиц возможна только после понимания как с этой базой работает код.